# URL Regex Crashed iOS App

Tags: iphone, regex, ios7

I have URL Regex Method like that;

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http://|https://|www.)((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)|([#^?'+!&%.@=*]))+((\\w)*|([0-9]*|([#^?'+!&%.@=*])))+";
NSPredicate *urlTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", urlRegEx];
NSArray *urlArray = [textView.text componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
```

It works great but however if URL contains '-' or '_' application crashed. Do you have any idea about problem?

Comment: Test case? iOS version? Have you tested it on a different iOS version?

Comment: Where does it crash? When evaluating the predicate or later on when you are trying to use the different parts of it?

Comment: No guys my urlArray crashed cause of textView.text predicate not valid for my urlRegex. I found solution.

Comment: We need a silver bullet for user generated URLs. However...

Comment: (Unfortunately) There is no silver bullet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok folks i have found solution like that;

```
NSString *urlRegEx = @"(http://|https://|www.)((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*)|([-_#^?'+!&%.@=*]))+((\\w)*|([0-9]*|([-_#^?'+!&%.@=*])))+";
```